# Escaping an ampersand character ('&') in a password for a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, special-characters

I have a password like 'X&Y' and I am trying to run a Ruby script that opens an SSH session, but the script breaks at the `&` character like :

*server: X
*server: bash: Y: command not found

Escaping the character like & doesn't help either. Ideas appreciated!

The code where it happens is at the ssh.exec:

```
pass="X\&Y"
Net::SSH.start( host_name, user, :password => pass ) do |ssh|
   #do stuff
   command = "sudo -S rm file"
   cmd = "#{pass}|#{command}"
   ssh.exec(cmd) do |ch, stream, data|
     puts "*server:" + data.inspect
   end
end
```

Comment: where is the code where you are trying to escape the `&` in??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ssh like without `&` getting any special meaning:

```
ssh -t -t user@localhost "echo 'abc&def'"
abc&def
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Comment: What happens if you have `abc'def` instead of `abc&def` though?

Comment: The password itself is 'X&Y'

Comment: That is fine, provide your command here if it is not working for you.